# Static analysis for constant values

Tags: c++, c, static, analysis

If i understand correctly, static analysis can guess what values a variable can have, and deduce, for example, what path in the control flow graph will never be executed.

I have an array of constants strings CStr. A method GetValue takes an index in parameters and do some computation to find the actual index in CStr array and return the const string pointed at that index.

edit: The actual index is unique and constant for each parameter given to GetValue

Can static analysis guess that GetValue(x) will have a constant value ? If yes, how is it done ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *"Can static analysis guess that GetValue(x) will have a constant value ?"*

That totally depends on the capabilities and quality of your static code analysis tool.
From theory that's possible to detect, yes.

---

If you meant what the compiler can deduce about constant expressions, it also depends on the compiler's actual implementation.

The best hint you can give it, is using the `constexpr` keyword, e.g.

```
 constexpr int GetValue(int x);
```

---

> *"If yes, how is it done ?"*

That's a very broad field, and hard to give a concise answer here.
Basically a static code analysis tool keeps track about the call references of particular functions. If the result of these functions can be deduced being a value that is specified at compile time (e.g. due to static initialization), the actual valid size/index of an accessed address from a calling function is known, and can be marked as issue if it's out of bounds.

Comment: I am actually interrested in implementing such a detection, is there any technique name you can give me ?

Comment: @Kelvyne Boah, you're really referring to that last part of your question _"If yes, how is it done ?"_, that's a way too broad question to be answered here. Though, before starting from scratch, you might be interested in extending existing FOSS tools like the [Clang Static Analyzer](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/), or [cppcheck](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/).